# Does a compact camera that zooms and performs well exist?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, point-and-shoot

I just bought a casio exilim h-10 camera and quite frankly I am disappointed.
The picture quality is very poor and the video (even if it is HD 720 P) is even worse.
I am really looking for a camera with:

- a good optical zoom (8-12x)
- compact
- 6 Mp or more
- makes clear picture
- makes fine videos
- responsive

Does that exist ?

Thanks,

A Confused Lady.

Comment: Define "responsive" - are you talking about the lagtime between shutter button press and taking the photo, or something else?

Comment: When I take the picture I want it to do it on the spot and I'd expect it to "reload" fast enough ton take another quickly.

Comment: so yeah basically I am speaking of the lagtime between shutter button press an photo taken and the time once it is taken and the camera ready to shoot a new one.

Answer (score 4):

The Canon SX30IS (14.1MP Digital Camera with 35x Wide Angle Optical Image Stabilized Zoom and 2.7 Inch Wide LCD). It appears to be an incredible zoom: 35x (!) wide-angle optical zoom (24-840mm) with Optical Image Stabilizer, 720p HD video with stereo sound. May not be as compact as you want, but this is what I recommended to a friend recently for her trip to Africa.

- [Canon introduces PowerShot SX30IS superzoom](http://www.dpreview.com/news/1009/10091411sx30is.asp) (Digital Photography Review)
- [SX30IS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041RSPR8) (Amazon)
- [Official page](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/digital_cameras/powershot_sx30_is) (Canon)
- [Review](http://www.photographyblog.com/reviews/canon_powershot_sx30is_review/) (photographyblog.com) (link to [conclusion page](http://www.photographyblog.com/reviews/canon_powershot_sx30is_review/conclusion/))
- [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ak04O3FHJYI) of that world's longest optical zoom

Comment: thaks that would be an incredible camera :) but yeah I'm travelling a lot with 2 young kids and am already a bit overwhelmed with the things I have to carry around  I want something small :)

Comment: Although capable, this model is far from compact. The smaller-zoom SX130 would be though.

Answer (score 4):

What about something like a Canon G11 or G12?

http://www.dpreview.com/news/1009/10091412canong12.asp

Comment: they don't have quite the zoom range the poster is asking for (though perhaps with a lens attachment they would?)... that said, they're one of the best quality point & shoot cameras so well worth considering if zoom range can be sacrificed for quality

Answer (score 3):

The [s20 IS](http://www1.epinions.com/review/Canon_PowerShot_SX20_IS_Digital_Camera/content_487285558916) Satisfies your request. I used to shoot with the older version of this, the S2 IS and was very happy.

EDIT: The poster expressed that the s20 IS would be a bit too big. One can go smaller without a loss in image quality(in fact possibly an increase) by looking at the [Canon G11](http://www.dpreview.com/news/0908/09081908canong11.asp). This camera is compact and takes amazing photos. Now, unfortunately this falls a little short of your zoom request. The G11 has a 5x zoom, which is not quite your lower bound of 8mp. But you should consider this option.

Comment: thank you. But I really need something more compact. I use to have the canon powershot s3 is and it was a very good camera. Loved it. In fact it made me picky. But it is too big for what i need. the s 20 is would no doubt be a good camera though. Thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the question is still up, but if so your choices apparently came to these five:

- Canon Powershot SX 210 IS
- Fuji Finepix F70 EXR
- Nikon Coolpix S8000
- Panasonic Lumix ZS3
- Panasonic Lumix ZS7 (aka TZ10)

While I'm a big fan of Canon compacts, I'd suggest that you try the Lumix ZS7 due to its light weight, responsiveness and features balance.

From my (small I should stress) experience with it, the ZS7 seemed a quite responsive travel zoom camera for its size. The fact that it includes the full PASM (Program, Aperture, Shutter and Manual modes) set and a GPS adds even more value to it.

Just keep in mind that this is a very subjective decision and your best bet is to spend a few minutes with each one of the above cameras before deciding for one of them.

Comment: thanks a lot for your anwser I like the panasonic lumix zs7.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Nikon Coolpix P7000](http://www.neocamera.com/review.php?id=240). It falls just short on the zoom side of your request, with a 7X wide-angle lens. It has great image quality for a compact camera and plenty of features too. The only downside of these cameras is that they are on the slow side of things.

If you want something faster and more complex to use, then the [Fuji Finepix F300 EXR](http://www.neocamera.com/review.php?id=75) is another great choice. It has an ultra-wide angle 15X optical zoom lens, amazing image dynamic-range, very good image quality and is extremely fast at focusing when under typical conditions.

Comment: I'll have a goo look at these two. They seem interesting.

Comment: While reading about thes two I foun a few more camera that seems interesting. The powershot sx 210 is , the finepix 70 exr, the coolpix s 8000 , and the panasoni lumix DMC-253 and the 257. If have any comment or suggestion about these or others I'd be glad to hear about it. Thanks again for your anwser.

Comment: make that the panasonic DMC_zs3 and zs7 :P

Comment: Look at other models as you may but it does not make them higher quality ;) The Nikon P7000 and Fuji's with SuperCCDs (F70 EXR, F80 EXR, F300 EXR) are ahead in terms of quality and still have long zooms (10-15X). A few more quality compacts exist (Canon S95, Canon S90, Canon G12, Olympus XZ-1) but their zooms are far less than what you are looking for. Since you said 'responsive', I would go with the Fuji F300 EXR, it is the only here to use the same fast focus-system as a DSLR.